# how to import on Qpython

Tags: python-import, qpython

I'm a newbie to python trying to run this code on Qpython:

from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script

print "Your first variable is:", first

print "Your second variable is:", second

print "Your third is:", third

but the console keeps returning this value error: need more than one value to unpack.

Pls help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough arguments to unpack in this step

script, first, second, third = argv

try

script, = argv

Comment: ran it from terminal emulator with the number of args needed. Thanks